# Building AOSP kernel with debug filesystem

Tags: file-system, kernel, aosp

As mentioned in [android documention](https://source.android.com/docs/core/architecture/kernel/using-debugfs-12),  **Android 12** should not use debug filesystem in **user** mode.

I want to build AOSP 12.1 for some device, but building in user mode results to error below:

**files are incompatible: Runtime info and framework compatibility matrix are incompatible: No compatible kernel requirement found (kernel FCM version = 5)**

**for kernel requirement at matrix level 5, for config CONFIG_DEBUG_FS, value=y but required n**

This config (CONFIG_DEBUG_FS) isn't my defconfig. I also added **CONFIG_DEBUG_FS=n** config to defconfig, but no change. result kernel config (obj/KERNEL_OBJ/.config) after build is same (**CONFIG_DEBUG_FS=y**)

It seems that Android build system uses a **base config from host os**  OR  there are some **depencencies** to this config such that this config is ignored.

How to disable this config in android build system?

UPDATE

I tried "make KCONFIG_CONFIG=arch/arm64/config/vendor/my_defconf **menuconfig**" so my defconf was input to menuconfig.

I disabled CONFIG_DEBUG_FS by disabling PAGE_OWNER option. because there was a rule that if 3 specific config was set, this config will set automatically.

These caonfigs were PAGE_OWNER  && DEBUG_KERNEL && STACKTRACE_SUPPORT.

if all sets then debugfs will set. so I disabled PAGE_OWNER because two others were Mandatory or useful. Then I saved defconfig. such that so many configs changed. and I start to build kernel but too many errors was in result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I mentioned in question, for aosp 12.1 and above, you should unset "CONFIG_PAGE_OWNER" config in kernel config file to build in user mode. unsetting this option will unset CONFIG_DEBUG_FS